# Using the F# pipe symbol with an object constructor

Tags: syntax, f#, constructor, pipe

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to use the pipe operator |> into the creation of an object.  Currently I'm using a static member to create the object and just piping to that.  Here is the simplified version.

```
type Shape = 
    val points : Vector[]

    new (points) =
        { points = points; }

    static member create(points) =
        Shape(points)

    static member concat(shapes : Shape list) =
        shapes
            |> List.map (fun shape -> shape.points)
            |> Array.concat
            |> Shape.create
```

What I want to do ...

```
    static member concat(shapes : Shape list) =
        shapes
            |> List.map (fun shape -> shape.points)
            |> Array.concat
            |> (new Shape)
```

Is something like this possible?  I don't want to duplicate code by repeating my constructor with the static member create.

**Update**
Constructors are first-class functions as of F# 4.0

In F# 4.0 the correct syntax is.

```
    static member concat(shapes : Shape list) =
        shapes
            |> List.map (fun shape -> shape.points)
            |> Array.concat
            |> Shape
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's always

```
(fun args -> new Shape(args))
```

Comment: Uhg, so simple.  I tried so many different syntax's and didn't even think of using a fun.  Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, object constructors aren't composable. Discriminated union constructors don't seem to have this problem:

```
> 1 + 1 |> Some;;
val it : int option = Some 2
```

If you want to use the pipeline, Brian's answer is probably best. In this case, I'd consider just wrapping the entire expression with Shape( ).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification.  I'm going to stick with Brian's way for now just for constancy sake.  I like ending functions with easy to recognize types.  Maybe they will add support for this in the future.