# How to parse comments with FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm attempting to parse lisp-style comments from an s-expression language with FParsec. I got a bit of help with parsing single-line comments in this previous thread - [How to convert an FParsec parser to parse whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395139/how-to-convert-an-fparsec-parser)

While that was resolved, I still need to parse multiline comments. Here's the current code -

```
/// Read whitespace character as a string.
let spaceAsStr = anyOf whitespaceChars |>> fun chr -> string chr

/// Read a line comment.
let lineComment = pchar lineCommentChar >>. restOfLine true

/// Read a multiline comment.
/// TODO: make multiline comments nest.
let multilineComment =
    between
        (pstring openMultilineCommentStr)
        (pstring closeMultilineCommentStr)
        (charsTillString closeMultilineCommentStr true System.Int32.MaxValue)

/// Read whitespace text.
let whitespace =
    lineComment <|>
    multilineComment <|>
    spaceAsStr

/// Skip any white space characters.
let skipWhitespace = skipMany whitespace

/// Skip at least one white space character.
let skipWhitespace1 = skipMany1 whitespace
```

Unfortunately, the multilineComment parse never succeeds. Since this is a combinator, I can't put breakpoints or analyze why it won't work.

Any ideas why it won't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the bool argument for `closeMultilineCommentStr` to false

```
(charsTillString closeMultilineCommentStr false System.Int32.MaxValue)
```

Otherwise it will skip over the `closeMultilineCommentStr` string.

To make it work with nested comments

```
let rec multilineComment o=
    let ign x = charsTillString x false System.Int32.MaxValue
    between
        (pstring openMultilineCommentStr)
        (pstring closeMultilineCommentStr)
        (attempt (ign openMultilineCommentStr >>. multilineComment >>. ign closeMultilineCommentStr) <|> 
        ign closeMultilineCommentStr) <|o
```

Comment: Ah, wonderful! I was distracted by thinking it would be some deep underlying parser issue, but it turns out it was a boolean I specified thoughtlessly! Thank you!

Comment: Holy-moly that looks difficult! I'm glad I asked! I will be trying to grok that until I can get it :) Thanks again!

Comment: To think F# and FParsec were around since 2011 and I didn't know until recently... anyway, that's a smart way to support nested comment blocks, but most (if not all) languages don't support nested block comments, instead ending the block on the first `close comment` token. A point to consider for anyone who ends up here by searching.

Comment: It seems that this recursive version thinks this case valid: `(* foo (* bar *)`, and this `(* foo *) bar *)`, which is not consistent with most ML languages (I believe same goes for the Scheme/Lisp-y langs). To make it work, simply drop `>>. ign closeMultilineCommentStr` in the `attempt`.