# With FParsec, how does one use the manyCharsTill and between parsers and not fail on the closing string?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I'm trying to use FParsec to parse a TOML multi-line string, and I'm having trouble with the closing delimiter (`"""`).  I have the following parsers:

```ml
let controlChars = 
    ['\u0000'; '\u0001'; '\u0002'; '\u0003'; '\u0004'; '\u0005'; '\u0006'; '\u0007';
     '\u0008'; '\u0009'; '\u000a'; '\u000b'; '\u000c'; '\u000d'; '\u000e'; '\u000f';
     '\u0010'; '\u0011'; '\u0012'; '\u0013'; '\u0014'; '\u0015'; '\u0016'; '\u0017';
     '\u0018'; '\u0019'; '\u001a'; '\u001b'; '\u001c'; '\u001d'; '\u001e'; '\u001f';
     '\u007f']

let nonSpaceCtrlChars =
    Set.difference (Set.ofList controlChars) (Set.ofList ['\n';'\r';'\t'])

let multiLineStringContents : Parser<char,unit> =
    satisfy (isNoneOf nonSpaceCtrlChars)

let multiLineString         : Parser<string,unit> =
    optional newline >>. manyCharsTill multiLineStringContents (pstring "\"\"\"")
    |> between (pstring "\"\"\"") (pstring "\"\"\"") 

let test parser str =
    match run parser str with
    | Success (s1, s2, s3) -> printfn "Ok: %A %A %A" s1 s2 s3
    | Failure (f1, f2, f3) -> printfn "Fail: %A %A %A" f1 f2 f3
```

When I test `multiLineString` against an input like this:

```
test multiLineString "\"\"\"x\"\"\""
```

The parser fails with this error:

> Fail: "Error in Ln: 1 Col: 8 """x"""
>          ^ Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream. Expecting: '"""'

I'm confused by this.  Wouldn't the `manyCharsTill multiLineStringContents (pstring "\"\"\"")` parser stop at the `"""` for the `between` parser to find it?  Why is the parser eating all the input and then failing the `between` parser?

This seems like a relevant post: [How to parse comments with FParsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405032/how-to-parse-comments-with-fparsec)

But I don't see how the solution to that one differs from what I'm doing here, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`manyCharsTill` documentation](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.manyCharsTill) says (emphasis mine):

> `manyCharsTill cp endp` parses chars with the char parser `cp` until the parser `endp` succeeds. It stops **after `endp`** and returns the parsed chars as a string.

So you don't want to use `between` in combination with `manyCharsTill`; you want to do something like `pstring "\"\"\"" >>. manyCharsTill (pstring "\"\"\"")`.

But as it happens, I can save you a lot of work. I've been working on a TOML parser with FParsec myself in my spare time. It's far from complete, but the string part works and handles backslash escapes correctly (as far as I can tell: I've tested thoroughly but not exhaustively). The only thing I'm missing is the "strip first newline if it appears right after the opening delimiter" rule, which you've handled with `optional newline`. So just add that bit into my code below and you should have a working TOML string parser.

BTW, I am planning to license my code (if I finish it) under the MIT license. So I hereby release the following code block under the MIT license. Feel free to use it in your project if it's useful to you.

```
let pShortCodepointInHex = // Anything from 0000 to FFFF, *except* the range D800-DFFF
    (anyOf "dD" >>. (anyOf "01234567" <?> "a Unicode scalar value (range D800-DFFF not allowed)") .>>. exactly 2 isHex |>> fun (c,s) -> sprintf "d%c%s" c s)
    <|> (exactly 4 isHex <?> "a Unicode scalar value")

let pLongCodepointInHex = // Anything from 00000000 to 0010FFFF, *except* the range D800-DFFF
        (pstring "0000" >>. pShortCodepointInHex)
        <|> (pstring "000"  >>. exactly 5 isHex)
        <|> (pstring "0010" >>. exactly 4 isHex |>> fun s -> "0010" + s)
        <?> "a Unicode scalar value (i.e., in range 00000000 to 0010FFFF)"

let toCharOrSurrogatePair p =
    p |> withSkippedString (fun codePoint _ -> System.Int32.Parse(codePoint, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) |> System.Char.ConvertFromUtf32)

let pStandardBackslashEscape =
    anyOf "\\\"bfnrt"
    |>> function
        | 'b' -> "\b"      // U+0008 BACKSPACE
        | 'f' -> "\u000c"  // U+000C FORM FEED
        | 'n' -> "\n"      // U+000A LINE FEED
        | 'r' -> "\r"      // U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
        | 't' -> "\t"      // U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION a.k.a. Tab or Horizonal Tab
        | c   -> string c

let pUnicodeEscape =     (pchar 'u' >>. (pShortCodepointInHex |> toCharOrSurrogatePair))
                     <|> (pchar 'U' >>. ( pLongCodepointInHex |> toCharOrSurrogatePair))

let pEscapedChar = pstring "\\" >>. (pStandardBackslashEscape <|> pUnicodeEscape)

let quote = pchar '"'
let isBasicStrChar c = c <> '\\' && c <> '"' && c > '\u001f' && c <> '\u007f'
let pBasicStrChars = manySatisfy isBasicStrChar
let pBasicStr = stringsSepBy pBasicStrChars pEscapedChar |> between quote quote

let pEscapedNewline = skipChar '\\' .>> skipNewline .>> spaces
let isMultilineStrChar c = c = '\n' || isBasicStrChar c
let pMultilineStrChars = manySatisfy isMultilineStrChar


let pTripleQuote = pstring "\"\"\""

let pMultilineStr = stringsSepBy pMultilineStrChars (pEscapedChar <|> (notFollowedByString "\"\"\"" >>. pstring "\"")) |> between pTripleQuote pTripleQuote
```

Comment: Awesome!  Yeah, I found an older open-sourced thing that hadn't been touched in a couple years, so I forked it: https://github.com/aggieben/FPConfig.  I'm starting to rewrite some of it because I think the parser I started with is...overly procedural.

I was just about to post my own answer realizing my obvious mistake, but you beat me to the punch, so have some fake internet points! :-)

Comment: Oh, nice. Have you started work on integer parsing yet? If you haven't, I'll send you a PR with what I've done on integers. (FParsec has a nice int parser that handles hex, octal, binary, etc., but it doesn't forbid `-0xff` the way TOML does, so I rolled my own hex parser that forbids negative numbers). Actually, expect a couple of PRs in the next few days: I'll look over that project and contribute anything I've done recently that isn't already in there.

Comment: The existing TOML parser is supposedly v0.4-compliant, but I don't know that the tests that were there actually show that.  I'm working on a full rewrite and aiming for 0.5 because I think I can make the parser(s) much simpler.  I'm currently working on the `dev` branch.

Comment: what is `exactly`? I couldn't find it in FParsec v1.1.0, nor in you repo cloudRoutine/Toml.FSharp

Answer (score 3):

@rmunn provided a correct answer, thanks!  I also solved this in a slightly different way after playing with the FParsec API a bit more.  As explained in the other answer, The `endp` argument to `manyCharTill` was eating the closing `"""`, so I needed to switch to something that wouldn't do that.  A simple modification using `lookAhead` did the trick:

```
let multiLineString         : Parser<string,unit> =
    optional newline >>. manyCharsTill multiLineStringContents (lookAhead (pstring "\"\"\""))
    |> between (pstring "\"\"\"") (pstring "\"\"\"")
```