# Can I use the pipeline operator in F# to pass an argument to a constructor?

Tags: f#

This code reverses a string:

```
let reverse (s : string) = new string(s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev)
```

Can this be rewritten using the pipeline operator to pass the required argument to the `string()` constructor?  For example, this seems more idiomatic:

```
// Doesn't compile:
let reverse (s : string) = s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> new string
```

Similarly, why can't I use the `string` operator in the following way?

```
let reverse2 (s : string) = s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> string
```

Here it is in action:

```
> reverse2 "foo" ;;
val it : string = "System.Char[]"
```

It returns the type rather than "oof".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the F# pipe symbol with an object constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531178/using-the-f-pipe-symbol-with-an-object-constructor)

Comment: This should be possible in F# 4.0 when it comes out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the pipe operator may only be used with F# functions, it cannot be used with class constructors, member methods or static methods. The reason being that the overloading supported by these kinds of methods would complicate F#'s type inference. However, if you really want to use piping, you could map each element of the char Array to a String and then pipe that sequence into `Seq.concat ""`:

```
s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> Seq.map(string) |> String.concat ""
```

Or you could wrap the string constructor call in an F# method:

```
let stringCArrCtor (carr: char[]) =
    new string(carr)

s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> stringCArrCtor
```

And to answer your last question,

```
s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> string
```

can't be used because it is equivalent to

```
(s.ToCharArray() |> Array.rev).ToString()
```

and the Array ToString() method is not overridden so it just returns the default reflected type name.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Looking at the type signature of the `string` operator, how did you know that it wasn't just a function that took an object and returned a string?  I'm still stuck on my last question.

Comment: @Slack, if you hover over the string function, it will tell you that it is a function 'T -> string which "converts the argument to a string using ToString()". You can also see that it is part of the Operators namespace, where along with several other conversion functions (like int, long, float, ...), it gets special treatment by the compiler so that they work as optimized "overloaded" functions. See lines 4074-4091 in prim-types.fs in the source code.

Answer (score 9):

As Stephen mentioned, the best thing to do is to define a new function that calls the constructor. You can place it into a module named `String` (in some your namespace), so you'll get similar feeling as when working with other F# functions. I would probably use:

```
module String =
  let create (c:char[]) = new string(c)
```

The question of using constructors as first-class values appeared on SO before, but I cannot find my earlier answer anymore - there is one very crazy trick that gives you the ability, but it is an enormous hack (nobody should ever use it and some next version of F# is hopefuly going to disallow that). Anyway, you can use [statically resolved type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) to write the following:

```
let inline ctor< ^R, ^T when ^R : 
        (static member ``.ctor`` : ^T -> ^R)> (arg:^T) =
    (^R : (static member ``.ctor`` : ^T -> ^R) arg)
```

And use the function like this:

```
"ABC".ToCharArray() |> Array.rev |> ctor<string, _>;;
```

The `ctor` function essentially requires that the type specified as the first type parameter has a constructor and it calls the constructor (the other type parameter is the argument to the constructor and is inferred by the compiler). But this is really just a curiosity - defining your own function is the best approach.

Comment: Weird, that "hack" breaks fsi.exe 3.1 with:
error FS3066: Invalid member name. Members may not have name '.ctor' or '.cctor'