# F# type constructor doesn't act like a function

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

If I define a type like this:

```
type Foo = Items of seq<int>
```

I can create a `Foo` as follows:

```
Items [1;2;3]
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
[1;2;3] |> Items
```

The error message is:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    int list -> 'a    
but given a
    seq<int> -> Foo
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to convert an `int list` into a `seq<int>`? If the `Items` constructor was a normal function, I could invoke it either way:

```
let length ints = Seq.length ints
printfn "%A" (length [1;2;3])
printfn "%A" ([1;2;3] |> length)
```

Comment: Using constructors as first-class functions is fairly new functionality (ok, not that new but still).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531178/using-the-f-pipe-symbol-with-an-object-constructor .  This may be a bug.

Comment: OK. Does anyone know how to report a bug to the F# team at Microsoft?

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/new

Comment: @jpierson - Actually I think https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/new is the correct place for general language issues like this.  Your link would be appropriate for an issue that is seen on one platform but not another.

Comment: @kvb - Ok, I was under the assumption that VisualFSharp was mainly just internal Microsoft concerns such as tooling with Visual Studio and no so much the more general things like compiler bugs. Perhaps you are right.

Comment: Things have changed since 2017. The place to report F# issues is now https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues

Answer (score 4):

This is a covariance issue.
The type constructor function `Items` is `seq<int> -> Items`, but is given a `List<int>`, which you will have to explicitly upcast as F# does not do automatic subtype conversion.

```
type Foo = Items of int list
[1;2;3] |> Items //compiles
```

or use the relevant Module

```
type Foo = Items of int seq
[1;2;3] |> Seq.ofList |> Items //compiles
```

Comment: F# does do automatic subtype conversion in the other examples I gave. I'd like to know why this case behaves differently.

Comment: `>type Foo = Items of seq<int>;;
>Items;;
val it : arg0:seq<int> -> Foo = <fun:clo@18-5>`

`let length (ints: int seq) = Seq.length ints

> let length (ints: int seq) = Items ints;;
> length;;
val it : (seq<int> -> Foo) = <fun:it@20-3>`

Same type signature but still the same problem.  I'm pretty sure this is a bug.

Comment: @mydogisbox agreed. They might have intentionally kept constructor functions strict because of type inferencing issues. Worth filing an issue to confirm.

Comment: There is work to extend automatic casting but it doesn't cover this case at present. Here is a comment from Don Syme about it: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/849#issuecomment-635956283

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a guess than an answer but I suspect that the issue may be related to similar behavior in C# in that constructors cannot have type parameters. By default it is my understanding that F# functions are completely generic and only become specialized through type annotations and inference. If the inability for constructors to have type parameters is something that is baked into the CLR or .NET in general then it may explain why F# type constructors may not be able to follow this same generic by default behavior as is done for functions.

Comment: I'm my assumptions above are correct then the same workaround that is often used in C# may work in F# to create a static factory method on the type that then calls the constructor with the necessary type argument as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code to be like this:

```
> type Foo = Items of seq<int>;;
> Items;;
val it : arg0:seq<int> -> Foo = <fun:clo@18-5>

> let length (ints: int seq) = Items ints;;
> length;;
val it : (seq<int> -> Foo) = <fun:it@20-3>
```

The issue becomes even more apparent.  Nearly identical type signature but still the same problem.  I'm pretty sure this is a bug with using constructors as first-class functions.

Comment: Good point. I reported this as a bug. Let's see what they say.

Comment: `type Foo = Items of seq<int>;; let items = Items;; [1;2;3] |> items;;` works as well, which *IS* the same thing.